# How to save a list item into specific folder in SharePoint list using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, office365-restapi

I have to save items into SharePoint list where I have specific folders in it and I have to save the item into that particular folder based on the item. I've retrieved the items from specific folders but how to save a list item into specific folder in SharePoint list using REST API?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Right do you want a JavaScript, C# or other example?

Comment: @Arcan.NET have found the solution using listdata.svc check it out...thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use listdata.svc

```
var metadata={Title: "Title", Path: "/ServerRelativeUrl of your folder in the list"};
$.ajax({
                url: url + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/[List Name]",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify(metadata),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    self.options.success(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    self.options.error(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Great efforts sir..!! Thanks a lot. You saved my day..!! :-)